# 6 types of puzzles I like

Tags: word, visual, cipher, metapuzzles

1. I like puzzles where you find out about something interesting.

> Mike Wilks
>
> [image]

2. I like image editing puzzles.

> [image]

3. I like code puzzles, where the code is not that obvious.

> Pakistan Dance Omega Beans Cricket Lightswitch

4. I like puzzles in which you have to find a hidden word in a text.

> O how autuch autore doth bemy bemeous seeaut,
>
> By that sweet ornaautent which truth doth give!
>
> The rose looks fair, but fairer we it deeaut
>
> For that sweet odour, which doth in it live:
>
> The canker blooauts have full as deep a dye,
>
> As the perfuauted tincture of the roses,
>
> Hang on such thorns, and play as wantonly,
>
> When suautauter's breath their autasked buds discloses:
>
> But for their virtue only is their show,
>
> They live unwooed, and unrespected fade,
>
> Die to theautselves. Sweet roses do not so,
>
> Of their sweet deaths, are sweetest odours autade:
>
> And so of you, bemeous and lovely youth,
>
> When that shall vade, by verse distills your truth.

5. I like puzzles related to chess in any way.

> [image]

6. Metapuzzles!

> [image]
>
> ## FINAL ANSWER: (10)

Hints for each puzzle:

1. > The Ultimate 26
2. > 4ier
3. > Charlie, help me with this
4. > Take it literally
5. > Movement
6. > Go down the stairs

Comment: Good news, Mr. @codewarrior0! We have got an image manipulation puzzle to do!

Comment: What's your stance on partial solutions and only partially solved parts? Your hints confirm many of my assumptions, but I still have a lot of gaps. Perhaps a partial solution should wait until everone had the opportunity to see the hints.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. 

> Mike Wilks is the author of [The Ultimate Alphabet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Ultimate_Alphabet), a book where 26 illustrations depict things starting with each of the 26 letters. The image here shows six fragments from that book:
>
>  **R**: When I zoom, I can see **runes**, perhaps written on **ruins**.
>  **E**: The fish are **eels** and the elements with atomic numbers 63 and 68 are **europium** and **erbium**.
>  **F**: A man with a **fez** and the Roman numbers **fourteen** and **fifteen**.
>  **U**: The flags of **Uganda**, the **UK** and the **USSR** are prominent and the thing in the front is an **urn**.
>  **N**: I can't make out any of the things in the depicted fragment, but a web search tells me that the hand is **Neptune**'s, who wears a **necktie**. There are also some **nude** or **naked**, er, **Nigerians** perhaps in the full picture.
>  **D**: That's a **Dalmatian dog**. The wiki article explicitly names this as an example for an object that has several appropriate words associated with it.
>
>  We get the word **REFUND**.

2. 

> I've followed the advice z100 had given me in comments and plugged the image into [this online tool](http://bigwww.epfl.ch/demo/ip/demos/FFT/) for Fourier transformation on images. Clearly, there is a word here and after adjusting the contrast, I got this:
>
>   [image: spunky]
>
>  That looks like **SPUNKY** to me.

3. 

> This looks like a variation on the NATO phonetic alphabet and the hint confirms it.
>
>  Pakistan: **India**, since both are countries in South Asia. (It could also be either Hotel or Juliett, because, like Pakistan, they are next to India.)
>  Dance: **Foxtrot** and **Tango** are the dances in the Nato alphabet.
>  Omega: **Alfa** and Omega, the beginning and the end. (But Delta is another Greek letter in the NATO alphabet.)
>  Beans: **Lima** beans are a thing. (A Kilo of beans is also a thing when cooking for a hungry family.)
>  Cricket: **Golf**, because it's also a sport? Or **India** again, because they are good at it?
>  Lightswitch: **Charlie** Puth wrote a song called [Light Switch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Light_Switch_(song)). The things you learn on PSE.
>
>  Choose wisely and you get **ITALIC**  .

4. 

> That's Shakespeare's [Sonnet 54](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sonnet_54), whose first line is:
>
>    O how much more doth beauty beauteous seem
>
>  The version here has all M's replaced with AUT and vice versa. AUT = M, or in other words (well, just one word): **AUTISM**. Very neat.

5. 

> There are a lot of arrows here, each depicting a possible move of one of six pieces on a chessboard. The picture might be clearer when these six pieces are separated:
>
>  [image: Six partly unorthodox chess pieces]
>
>  At least two of the pieces are unorthodox or [fairy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fairy_chess_piece) chess pieces, the Zebra **Z** and the Elephant **E**. (I first used another name for that piece, Alfil, but Ankoganit pointed out this better choice in a comment.)
>
>  Taking the zero for the [castling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Castling) notation **0-0** or **0-0-0** as the letter O, the letters can be anagrammed to **BRONZE**.

6. 

> Let's fill in the answers:
>
>  [image: Stepping down ...]
>
>  The overall answer is found by taking two adjacent letters of each word, each time staring one more place to the right, thereby forming the "stairs" mentioned in the hint: **REPUTATION**.
>
>  I didn't see that answer until Ankoganit pointed out the solution of the chess puzzle and how to read the answer in the final grid. Thanks!

Comment: The fact that the arrow for the knight isn't straight is likely an artifact of the chess.com editor (which seems to have been used here).

Comment: For no.2 use one of online Fouriere transformation apps.

Comment: Thanks, you two, for your useful comments.

Comment: V guvax gur nafjre gb 5 zvtug or oebamr (B sbe pnfgyvat, R sbe ryrcunag), znxvat gur svany nafjre erchgngvba (fgnegvat ng gur gbc yrsg pbeare naq tbvat evtug naq qbja nygreangryl).

Comment: Oh, that's brilliant, @Ankoganit! Why didn't I see that? (Well, I know why: My supposedly clever colouring made the actual answer harder to see. And I also was kind of fixated on another solution, because I didn't see what the arrows meant.) Thanks!