# 9 types of puzzles I like

Tags: word, visual, metapuzzles

This is a sequel to [6 types of puzzles I like](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/121872/6-types-of-puzzles-i-like).

---

1. **You need to clean up, or things will get more messy...** - [outer-space](/questions/tagged/outer-space)

> MS - Rose
>
> MATE - Lagoon
>
> MIS - Pegasus
>
> MSO - Heart
>
> MSI - Whirlpool
>
> MEI - ?

2. **Ay Bee Cee Dee** - [rebus](/questions/tagged/rebus)

> [image]

3. **You'll be in Utah for very long** - [geography](/questions/tagged/geography)

> What set of 3 words do you like the most?
>
> 1. Start, Follow, Rails
> 2. Unattached, Houseboat, Neutron
> 3. Speculative, Servants, Performed
> 4. Eats, Laying, Awaits
> 5. Medicines, Precise, Veteran
> 6. Foiled, Interactive, Eaten
> 7. Jaguar, Surapassed, Emailed
> 8. Pollen, Cuff, Methodical
> 9. Paddocks, Skipped, Fascinate

4. **A bandit may help you** - [music](/questions/tagged/music)

> ## Well, I listen to the radio
>
> (Cobweb. Lukewarm. Doll. Girl. Oscar. Rag. Lukewarm. Honeymoon. Little Man.)

5. **Scrambled words** - [anagram](/questions/tagged/anagram)

> The following phrases are related to words that anagrams of each other. Find the other one.
>
> 1. deadly nightshade
> 2. talking to a stupid person
> 3. cyclopropane + cycloalkane
>
> Note: I used [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wiktionary:Main_Page) for this puzzle.

6. **Something you can't see** - [visual](/questions/tagged/visual)

> [Puzzle 6](https://imgur.com/a/DHKiGMg) (There's no 18+ imagery, the imgur site is mistaken)

7. **I like dots!** - [cipher](/questions/tagged/cipher)

> INMAMMINIINMAIAANMAMMIMANIA

8. **No vowel acids** [science](/questions/tagged/science)

> 1. LNN
> 2. SPRGN
> 3. THRNN
> 4. SLCN
> 5. PRLN
> 6. LNN
> 7. SRN
> 8. THRNN
> 9. SLCN

9. **A "board game" metapuzzle** - [metapuzzle](/questions/tagged/metapuzzle)

> I remember this game my mom gifted me from my tenth birthday, the game was based on the dark red squares in the center. Whats it's name again?
>
> [image]

**What's the name of the board game and what is the final answer?**

Comment: #1 is a constellation puzzle.

Comment: Hey poco, is there a reason why you didn't put puzzle 6 directly in the image?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For part 4 the answer is

> CANNONADE

If we look at the

> track listing for [Radiohead's Hail to the Thief](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hail_to_the_Thief), most of the words appear in alternative titles to the tracks 3,1,14,14,?,14,1,4,4. The other word is OSCAR which is O in the NATO phonetic alphabet. Substituting A=1, B=2 et. gives the answer.

As for puzzle 9 we note

> answers overlap in the start and end in pairs CANNONA(DE)TRIMENTS, ISOPTER(AN)TIPASTI, ANDROME(DA)YDREAMT, REFRESH(EN)NEAGONS. Note the alternative anagram to misc544 for Q5. This suggests a layout in the grid [image: layout] (thanks to Stiv), where the central letters are DEAN and Stiv notes the exterior word ARTISTIC). (Acknowledging solutions from Arturo, Carmiester, DqwertC, misc544 and Stiv). The board itself sort of resembles LUDO or PARCHEESI, but not quite.

Comment: The answer to the rebus in part 2 is rot13([RAARNTBAF](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/enneagon)) which fits perfectly into the missing part of the cross-shaped design. Feel free to add this in to your answer...

Comment: Also, [here's an image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SsSlo.png) you can use. Note that an 8-letter word is spelled out round the outside...

Comment: Congrats! You'll get the puzzle1(MIT), also (un)fun fact, someone solved this on discord like 8 hours ago.

Answer (score 8):

(Very) Partial answer:

Subpuzzle 3 is all about

> What3Words (a way to encode Earth's coordinates in sets of three words). Each 3 word set points to a letter built to be seen from space. For example, the first set (Start, Follow, Rails) points to [this big D in St. George, Utah](https://what3words.com/start.follow.rails). Joining all the letters together we get the word DETRIMENT.

Subpuzzle 7 apears to be about

> Morse code, given that the four letters used (A,I,M,N) are the letters made up of two symbols in morse code (A=.- | I=.. | M=-- | N=-.). The string that is formed with them is ..-.--.-----..-.....-.--.-...-.--.--.-----..--.--....-, which has the word EVACUATE in the middle (like this: ..-.--.-----..-.//./...-/.-/-.-./..-/.-/-/.//--.-----..--.--....-)

UPDATE: Puzzle 8 is solved too

> These letters are aminoacids with their vowels removed. If we take the canonical letter associated to each aminoacid, we get the answer ANTIPASTI. (A - Alanine, N - Asparagine, T - Threonine, I - Isoleucine, P - Proline, A - Alanine, S - Serine, T - Threonine, I - Isoleucine)

Comment: What a coincidence! I have rot13(jung guerr jbeqf) open in another of my tabs! (It was open before I opened this question.)

Comment: @misc544 by which I mean first time I opened this question.

Comment: [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Messier_object#Messier_objects) should help with #1

Comment: Looks like part seven involves (rot13) qvivqvat gur fgevat vagb tebhcf bs fvk naq vagrecergvat qbgf nf oenvyyr

Comment: Carmeister's suggestion for #7 above is spot on - if you do this you should produce the answer rot13(QNLQERNZG) - the spelling may be unorthodox, but it fits with the growing trend that all answers here have 9 letters...

Answer (score 6):

Partial answer:
The answer to puzzle one is:

> Andromeda!

Figuring it out:

> With a hint from caPNCApn about Messier objects, using the Beghilos cipher (calculators, anyone?) on most objects in the subpuzzle determined the position of the object in the Messier object list. For example, M15 (Pegasus) is MIS, which is also Pegasus. However, it doesn't work on the mate one, which is M "eight". So the answer to puzzle one is Andromeda (M31, MEI).

Puzzle 5:

> 1. ATROPINES

> 2. PATRONISE

> 3. SPIROTANE

Thus, the answer is:

> APERTIONS

Figuring it out:

> I tried atropine, then saw one answer by DQwertyC saying that words should probably be nine letters, so I looked for nine letter words and then I thought of plurals, then I found these by looking in the "Anagrams" section! (That's a way to find new words and expand your vocabulary.)

Comment: @misc544 nice work on the anagram one

Comment: @caPNCApn yes, but I don't really know what the 2nd word has to do with the "talk to a stupid person" clue, it only has "say to say" relation

Comment: see the third meaning [here](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/patronize#English)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148016/discussion-between-misc544-and-capncapn).

Comment: Note that re #5, there is [an additional possibility on Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/isopteran#English) - it's not clear to me at this stage which one is intended... Perhaps worth keeping that in mind for when the metapuzzle becomes fully solvable...

Answer (score 5):

We can find the answer to part six through:

> A good old flood fill. The word "refreshen" is seen in the lower left corner, as an area that has slightly higher opacity than the rest of the background. [image]

For the overall meta-puzzle, I've noticed that

> Most answers seem to be 9 characters long. Maybe we need to revisit some of the answers that aren't?