# 13 puzzles I like

Tags: word, visual, metapuzzles

This is the third installment (???) to this series: [6 types of puzzles I like](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/121872/6-types-of-puzzles-i-like), [9 types of puzzles I like](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/122039/9-types-of-puzzles-i-like), **13 puzzles I like** (and yes, I removed "types of" because I cannot think of more puzzles I especially like).

---

1. **Easy Synonym Puzzle!** - [wordplay](/questions/tagged/wordplay)

> Don't tell truths.
>
> TruthStopFriendStraightZ

2. **Do not look behind you** - [visual](/questions/tagged/visual)

> [image]
>
> HINT:
>
> > [image]

3. **Please play fair** - [cipher](/questions/tagged/cipher)

> Dog: Fox, play fair.
>
> Fox: Yeah, ok! HEHNXILZWZADIOWHTOJQEQZWMFUK.

4. **A beautiful step** - [steganography](/questions/tagged/steganography)
   .                .

> THAT MAN IS SO SLIM
> OR HE'S JUST THIN.
> OUT RIDING THE EMU,
> SLIGHT TROUBLE RLLY

5. **Double Meanings** - [word](/questions/tagged/word)

> This word can mean:
>
> 1. sparkle
> 2. bubbly
>
> or it can mean:
>
> 1. sparkle
> 2. bubbly
> 3. brilliant
>
> HINT:
>
> > _ _ F _ _ _ _ _ _ _

6. **Lost In Translation** - [language](/questions/tagged/language)

> てちなけてくけおてと
>
> Yes, あ means A.

7. **Video rebus** - [rebus](/questions/tagged/rebus)

> [image]
>
> HINT:
>
> > What can an eye do?

8. **Surrounded** - [geography](/questions/tagged/geography)

> EES
>
> AAAIPTT
>
> AFP
>
> BELNZ
>
> SUY
>
> BG
>
> BBCPU
>
> CH
>
> BEPPV
>
> CP

9. **I am not a bird!** - [affix-riddle](/questions/tagged/affix-riddle)

> My prefix is screaming.
>
> My infix is not lofty.
>
> My suffix is a 50/50.

10. **I don't know what to name this one** - [enigmatic-puzzle](/questions/tagged/enigmatic-puzzle)

> Control Variable: ️
>
> wVSj1sF3

11. **Anagramming nightmare** - [anagram](/questions/tagged/anagram)

> Each set has phrases related to words that are anagrams of themselves. Find the other one. (No capitalized words)
>
> 1. Of a kind, Black person, Rebirth
> 2. Existence, To lower, Flour, Neighborhood, Arabic adjective
>
> Take note I made this using [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wiktionary:Main_Page)

12. **I don't know what to name this** - [music](/questions/tagged/music)

> List of music I should listen to:
>
> 1. Cupid (Twin Version) - It's been 30 days since I've listened to this.
> 2. The Sound of Silence - Well, basically...
> 3. Africa - Was there drums in this song? I forgot.
> 4. STOP TRYING TO BE GOD - I listened to this on the ship.
> 5. 6 Foot 7 Foot - I remember showing this to my mom.
> 6. Delicate - I remember listening to this and I tripped on the stairs, LOL.
> 7. Fireflies - Just found out they play this on the disco.
> 8. Earth - I cried at that part where Meghan Trainor sang.
> 9. Life of the Party - I got in trouble when I listened to this at school.
> 10. Closer - After 4 years, I wanted to listen to this song.

13. **NO, NOt the NONOgram!** [metapuzzles](/questions/tagged/metapuzzles) [nonogram](/questions/tagged/nonogram)

> [image]
>
> ## The final answer must be 4 words that are related to each other.

Comment: Stiv suggested in a [comment below](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/122116/13-puzzles-i-like/122144#comment341061_122162) that there might be a mistake in the top-left nonogram grid, and that the answer is intended to be ROT13(CYNHQVGF).  Can you confirm/deny?

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain yes it is.

Comment: @1357924680a Yes it is, also spoilers please

Answer (score 13):

Since I suspect this will be another group effort to solve in totality, let's kick this off with the solutions to six of the sub-puzzles (half of them)...

My answers so far:

> 1. LYGOPHOBIA
>  4. TIMOROUSLY
>  8. DISSONANCE
>  9. YELLOWTAIL
>  11. GREENBEANS
>  12. NEEDLEFISH
>
>  Note that all have 10 letters.

**Puzzle 1:**

"Don't tell truths" suggests that...

> the 'Synonym' in the title is a lie - instead we are looking for antonyms or opposites of some kind to the five concatenated words beneath (TruthStopFriendStraightZ). This yields:
>
>  Truth → LIE
>  Stop → GO
>  Friend → FOE
>  Straight → BI
>  Z → A (ends of the alphabet)
>
>  String these together = LIE.GO.FOE.BI.A, or **LYGOPHOBIA** (fear of the dark).

**Puzzle 4:**

This puzzle has a tricksy element to it, which I didn't notice until I tried to...

> ...*edit* the question for an entirely unrelated reason! I was wondering whether those two stray dots after the 'steganography' tag needed to be edited out as a mistake. However, when the source is viewed you see that this string of text is actually presented as follows (implying that this is deliberate, for steganographic purposes):
>
>  [image: Image of question 4 source code]
>
>  (The small stepped offset in each line is probably being referred to in the 'step' of the sub-puzzle's title...)
>
>  To find the answer, remove all letters that appear anywhere between those two dots in this new formatted view:
>
>  [image: Crossing out the central letters]
>
>  Now read off the remaining letters in order (along each line and down) and the 10-letter answer **TIMOROUSLY** remains!

**Puzzle 8:**

The letters represent...

> the initial letters of countries that all share a border with a common neighbour (which is in effect *surrounded* by them):
>
>  EES = DJIBOUTI (Eritrea, Ethiopia, Somalia)
>  AAAIPTT = IRAN (Afghanistan, Armenia, Azerbaijan, Iraq, Pakistan, Turkiye, Turkmenistan)
>  AFP = SPAIN (Andorra, France, Portugal)
>  BELNZ = SOUTH AFRICA (Botswana, Eswatini, Lesotho, Namibia, Zimbabwe)
>  SUY = OMAN (Saudi Arabia, UAE, Yemen)
>  BG = NETHERLANDS (Belgium, Germany)
>  BBCPU = ARGENTINA (Bolivia, Brazil, Chile, Peru, Uruguay)
>  CH = NICARAGUA (Costa Rica, Honduras)
>  BEPPV = COLOMBIA (Bolivia, Ecuador, Panama, Paraguay, Venezuela)
>  CP = ECUADOR (Colombia, Peru)
>
>  Reducing these identified countries to their initials gives **DISSONANCE**.

**Puzzle 9:**

*My prefix is screaming.*

> **YELL**

*My infix is not lofty.*

> **LOW**

*My suffix is a 50/50.*

> Either **HEAD** or **TAIL**. However, since [YELLOWHEAD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yellowhead_(bird)) *is* a bird, the answer (found by concatenating/overlapping the three -fixes) must be YELL+LOW+TAIL = **[YELLOWTAIL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yellowtail_(fish))**, a type of fish!

**Puzzle 11:**

*1. Of a kind, Black person, Rebirth*

> These work out as: [genre](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/genre#English), rot13(artre), and [regen](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/regen#English).
>
>  The other anagram of these words is **GREEN**. (NB I have provided the second only in its rot13-ed form, as this word - the reverse spelling of the third - is considered an 'often offensive' term...)

*2. Existence, To lower, Flour, Neighborhood, Arabic adjective*

> These work out as: [banes](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/banes#English), [basen](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/basen#English), [besan](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/besan#English), [nabes](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/nabes#English) and [nesba](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/nesba#English).
>
>  The other anagram of these words is **BEANS**.

Putting this all together, we get:

> GREEN+BEANS = **GREENBEANS**

**Puzzle 12:**

These songs...

> all have **NATO phonetic alphabet words** in their lyrics, somewhere near a phrase clued in the accompanying text.

1. Cupid (Twin Version) - It's been 30 days since I've listened to this.

> Artist: FIFTY FIFTY
>  Lyric: *Been counting the days since **NOVEMBER**...*

2. The Sound of Silence - Well, basically...

> Artist: Simon and Garfunkel
>  Lyric: *And **ECHO**ed in the wells of silence...*

3. Africa - Was there drums in this song? I forgot.

> Artist: Toto
>  Lyric: *I hear the drums **ECHO**ing tonight...*

4. STOP TRYING TO BE GOD - I listened to this on the ship.

> Artist: Travis Scott
>  Lyric: ***DELTA** and I ship it overnight...*

5. 6 Foot 7 Foot - I remember showing this to my mom.

> Artist: Lil Wayne ft. Corey Gunz
>  Lyric: *Yeah, word to my mama, I'm out of my **LIMA** bean...*

6. Delicate - I remember listening to this and I tripped on the stairs, LOL.

> Artist: Taylor Swift
>  Lyric: ***ECHO**es of your footsteps on the stairs...*

7. Fireflies - Just found out they play this on the disco.

> Artist: Owl City
>  Lyric: *A **FOXTROT** above my head, A sock hop beneath my bed, A disco ball is just hanging by a thread...*

8. Earth - I cried at that part where Meghan Trainor sang.

> Artist: Lil Dicky (this was a charity single sung by many artists)
>  Lyric: MEGHAN TRAINOR: *We love you, **INDIA**...*

9. Life of the Party - I got in trouble when I listened to this at school.

> Artist: Kanye West
>  Lyric: ***SIERRA** Canyon when daddy got his own school...*

10. Closer - After 4 years, I wanted to listen to this song.

> Artist: Chainsmokers
>  Lyric: *Four years, no calls, Now you're looking pretty in a **HOTEL** bar...*

Stringing all of these together gives us:

> NOVEMBER ECHO ECHO DELTA LIMA ECHO FOXTROT INDIA SIERRA HOTEL, which spells **NEEDLEFISH**.

Answer (score 10):

*This is a community wiki compilation of all the excellent answers provided by others, to get everything in one place.  Please upvote the other answers where people actually solved the puzzles.*

Here are the solutions to each of the individual puzzles:

---

1. **Easy synonym puzzle!** [wordplay](/questions/tagged/wordplay)
    <sup>- *[solved by Stiv](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/122120)*</sup>

"Don't tell truths" suggests that...

> the 'Synonym' in the title is a lie - instead we are looking for antonyms or opposites of some kind to the five concatenated words beneath (TruthStopFriendStraightZ). This yields:
>
>  Truth → LIE
>  Stop → GO
>  Friend → FOE
>  Straight → BI
>  Z → A (ends of the alphabet)
>
>  String these together = LIE.GO.FOE.BI.A, or **LYGOPHOBIA** (fear of the dark).

---

2. **Do not look behind you** [visual](/questions/tagged/visual)
    <sup>- *[solved by Ivan Smirnov](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/122147)*</sup>

> The grid with letters can be uniquely split into given polyominoes such that the letters covered by each polyomino form the connected region on the keyboard.

The resulting figure is

> [image]

Now we note that

> each connected region on the keyboard is of shape O, C or L and "embraces" some letter. Those letters are E, I, Z, S, R, A, T, R, E, R (in the order in which the figures are given in the hint), and **RASTERIZER** is the only anagram.

The hint helped me in finding the solution:

> first, I noticed that the largest 8-cell region fits to the top and the letters are pretty close on the keyboard. Then the cross fitted nicely to the left-top with the same property.

> Next, I used some computer assistance to generate the assignment (in fact, it only generated admissible positions for all polyominoes).

> Finally, I realized that all connected regions on the keyboard are of the peculiar shape and looked at the surrounded characters. The colored square in the hint suggested that I'm on the right way.

---

3. **Please play fair** [cipher](/questions/tagged/cipher)
    <sup>- *[solved by Daniel S](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/122122)*</sup>

> It is [Playfair encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Playfair_cipher), using the grid
>
> `T H E Q U`
> `I C K B R`
> `O W N F X`
> `J M P S V`
> `L A Z Y D`
>
>  The grid is derived from the pangramatic phrase "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog".
>
>  Solving the cipher yields the answer **ANALYTICAL**.

---

4. **A beautiful step** [steganography](/questions/tagged/steganography)
    <sup>- *[solved by Stiv](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/122120)*</sup>

This puzzle has a tricksy element to it, which I didn't notice until I tried to...

> ...*edit* the question for an entirely unrelated reason! I was wondering whether those two stray dots after the 'steganography' tag needed to be edited out as a mistake. However, when the source is viewed you see that this string of text is actually presented as follows (implying that this is deliberate, for steganographic purposes):
>
>  [image: Image of question 4 source code]
>
>  (The small stepped offset in each line is probably being referred to in the 'step' of the sub-puzzle's title...)
>
>  To find the answer, remove all letters that appear anywhere between those two dots in this new formatted view:
>
>  [image: Crossing out the central letters]
>
>  Now read off the remaining letters in order (along each line and down) and the 10-letter answer **TIMOROUSLY** remains!

---

5. **Double Meanings** [word](/questions/tagged/word)
    <sup>- *not yet solved*</sup>

---

6. **Lost in Translation** [language](/questions/tagged/language)
    <sup>- *[solved by Kusane Hexaku](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/122127)*</sup>

> The key thing to notice is that all the characters given are all within the first 5 rows of the Hiragana. More specifically, *they are less than 26*.
>  This is furthermore supported by the `あ = A` clue. While あ is indeed the a sound, it is also the first character of the Hiragana, just like how A is the first letter of the English alphabet.
> Taking their position into the hiragana gives `19 17 21 9 19 8 9 5 19 20`, which when translated into A1Z26 gives the answer **SQUISHIEST**.

---

7. **Video rebus** [rebus](/questions/tagged/rebus)
    <sup>- *[solved by GentlePurpleRain](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/122162)*</sup>

Ever since I first saw this, I thought that the **-TION** was clueing subtraction, but I wasn't sure what to subtract it from.

As I played around with it some more, I came up with

> EQUATION

Removing the -TION and playing around with other words that contained the remaining letters, I came up with

> IN AD EQUA(-TION) SEE

or

> **INADEQUACY**

---

8. **Surrounded** [geography](/questions/tagged/geography)
    <sup>- *[solved by Stiv](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/122120)*</sup>

The letters represent...

> the initial letters of countries that all share a border with a common neighbour (which is in effect *surrounded* by them):
>
>  EES = DJIBOUTI (Eritrea, Ethiopia, Somalia)
>  AAAIPTT = IRAN (Afghanistan, Armenia, Azerbaijan, Iraq, Pakistan, Turkiye, Turkmenistan)
>  AFP = SPAIN (Andorra, France, Portugal)
>  BELNZ = SOUTH AFRICA (Botswana, Eswatini, Lesotho, Namibia, Zimbabwe)
>  SUY = OMAN (Saudi Arabia, UAE, Yemen)
>  BG = NETHERLANDS (Belgium, Germany)
>  BBCPU = ARGENTINA (Bolivia, Brazil, Chile, Peru, Uruguay)
>  CH = NICARAGUA (Costa Rica, Honduras)
>  BEPPV = COLOMBIA (Bolivia, Ecuador, Panama, Paraguay, Venezuela)
>  CP = ECUADOR (Colombia, Peru)
>
>  Reducing these identified countries to their initials gives **DISSONANCE**.

---

9. **I am not a bird!** [affix-riddle](/questions/tagged/affix-riddle)
    <sup>- *[solved by Stiv](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/122120)*</sup>

*My prefix is screaming.*

> **YELL**

*My infix is not lofty.*

> **LOW**

*My suffix is a 50/50.*

> Either **HEAD** or **TAIL**. However, since [YELLOWHEAD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yellowhead_(bird)) *is* a bird, the answer (found by concatenating/overlapping the three -fixes) must be YELL+LOW+TAIL = **[YELLOWTAIL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yellowtail_(fish))**, a type of fish!

---

10. **I don't know what to name this one** [enigmatic-puzzle](/questions/tagged/enigmatic-puzzle)
     <sup>- *[solved by Kusane Hexaku](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/122127)*</sup>

> Control Variable = Control V = Ctrl+V = PASTE,
>  + Emoji of a BIN = PASTEBIN.
>  https://pastebin.com/wVSj1sF3 has a single piece of text:
>  
>    **oh ee ess oh pee aitch ay gee you ess**
>  
>  Each one these sounds like a letter, which gives the answer **OESOPHAGUS**.

---

11. **Anagramming nightmare** [anagram](/questions/tagged/anagram)
     <sup>- *[solved by Stiv](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/122120)*</sup>

*1. Of a kind, Black person, Rebirth*

> These work out as: [genre](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/genre#English), rot13(artre), and [regen](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/regen#English).
>
>  The other anagram of these words is **GREEN**. (NB I have provided the second only in its rot13-ed form, as this word - the reverse spelling of the third - is considered an 'often offensive' term...)

*2. Existence, To lower, Flour, Neighborhood, Arabic adjective*

> These work out as: [banes](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/banes#English), [basen](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/basen#English), [besan](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/besan#English), [nabes](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/nabes#English) and [nesba](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/nesba#English).
>
>  The other anagram of these words is **BEANS**.

Putting this all together, we get:

> GREEN+BEANS = **GREENBEANS**

---

12. **I don't know what to name this** [music](/questions/tagged/music)
     <sup>- *[solved by Stiv](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/122120)*</sup>

These songs...

> all have **NATO phonetic alphabet words** in their lyrics, somewhere near a phrase clued in the accompanying text.

1. Cupid (Twin Version) - It's been 30 days since I've listened to this.

> Artist: FIFTY FIFTY
>  Lyric: *Been counting the days since **NOVEMBER**...*

2. The Sound of Silence - Well, basically...

> Artist: Simon and Garfunkel
>  Lyric: *And **ECHO**ed in the wells of silence...*

3. Africa - Was there drums in this song? I forgot.

> Artist: Toto
>  Lyric: *I hear the drums **ECHO**ing tonight...*

4. STOP TRYING TO BE GOD - I listened to this on the ship.

> Artist: Travis Scott
>  Lyric: ***DELTA** and I ship it overnight...*

5. 6 Foot 7 Foot - I remember showing this to my mom.

> Artist: Lil Wayne ft. Corey Gunz
>  Lyric: *Yeah, word to my mama, I'm out of my **LIMA** bean...*

6. Delicate - I remember listening to this and I tripped on the stairs, LOL.

> Artist: Taylor Swift
>  Lyric: ***ECHO**es of your footsteps on the stairs...*

7. Fireflies - Just found out they play this on the disco.

> Artist: Owl City
>  Lyric: *A **FOXTROT** above my head, A sock hop beneath my bed, A disco ball is just hanging by a thread...*

8. Earth - I cried at that part where Meghan Trainor sang.

> Artist: Lil Dicky (this was a charity single sung by many artists)
>  Lyric: MEGHAN TRAINOR: *We love you, **INDIA**...*

9. Life of the Party - I got in trouble when I listened to this at school.

> Artist: Kanye West
>  Lyric: ***SIERRA** Canyon when daddy got his own school...*

10. Closer - After 4 years, I wanted to listen to this song.

> Artist: Chainsmokers
>  Lyric: *Four years, no calls, Now you're looking pretty in a **HOTEL** bar...*

Stringing all of these together gives us:

> NOVEMBER ECHO ECHO DELTA LIMA ECHO FOXTROT INDIA SIERRA HOTEL, which spells **NEEDLEFISH**.

---

13. **NO, NOt the NONOgram!** [metapuzzles](/questions/tagged/metapuzzles)[nonogram](/questions/tagged/nonogram)
     <sup>- *not yet solved*</sup>

Comment: My own discovery: rot13 + rot5 RSSRERIRFPR JNF GUR NAFJRE SBE 0.

Answer (score 8):

UPDATED with post hint thoughts 20230829.

Adding to Stiv's answer, puzzle 3

> THE WORD ANALYTICAL IS THE ANSWER

because

> it is [Playfair encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Playfair_cipher) using the grid
>  `T H E Q U` 
>  `I C K B R` 
>  `O W N F X` 
>  `J M P S V` 
>  `L A Z Y D`.
>  The grid being derived from the pangramatic phrase "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog".

Initial observation on puzzle 2

> There's a preponderance of letters from the left side of the QWERTY keyboard.

Reaction to hint on puzzle 5

> The word `EFFERVESCE` fits and means to sparkle or to bubble, but there's something that I'm missing.

Initial observation on puzzle 6:

> The [hiragana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hiragana#Table_of_hiragana) transliterate as `TE TI NA KE TE KU KE O TE TO`

Initial observation on puzzle 7:

> The yellow bar indicates an AD on YouTube, but AD SUM I TION is not a word.

Some initial thoughts on puzzle 10

> This seems to be saying that we should interpret the base64 quantity in binary (hence the `bin` symbol). This gives `110000010101010010100011110101101100000101110111` which is a string of 48 bits. Often writing this as a black and white pixelated image is the next step, but there 48 has quite a few factorisations and although some seemed to have structure, I couldn't spot a 10-letter message.

Thoughts on the meta

> It looks like we're supposed to fill out the 12x10 grids as follows
>  `LYGOPHOBIA`
> `RASTERIZER`
> `ANALYTICAL`
> `TIMOROUSLY`
> `??????????`
> `SQUISHIEST`
> `??????????`
> `DISSONANCE`
> `YELLOWTAIL`
> `OESOPHAGUS`
> `GREENBEANS`
> `NEEDLEFISH`
>  and then extract substrings of our words consistent with the nonogram to form four clues with 29, 21, 37, and 38 letters respectively. So for example the first rectangle might being `GO POSER IT ICS???`

Comment: The second hiragana is "chi"

Comment: Yeah, I'd spell it that way too, though others (including the Japanese themselves) spell it the way Daniel S did, afaik.

Comment: Don't forget the middle bit says "A to Y" - I think we need to arrange them in alphabetical order...  Unfortunately that means we need to know all 12 before we can fully arrange them for sure! (Also, they are **12**x10...)

Comment: @Stiv Good points both; I;'ve corrected the 12.

Answer (score 7):

Okay, here is my contribution to this thread :3

**Puzzle 6** - Solved

> The key thing to notice is that all the characters given are all within the first 5 rows of the Hiragana. More specifically, *they are less than 26*.
>  This is furthermore supported by the `あ = A` clue. While あ is indeed the a sound, it is also the first character of the Hiragana, just like how A is the first letter of the English alphabet.
> Taking their position into the hiragana gives `19 17 21 9 19 8 9 5 19 20`, which when translated into A1Z26 gives the answer **SQUISHIEST**.

**Puzzle 10** - Solved

> Control Variable = Control V = Ctrl+V = PASTE,
> + Emoji of a BIN = PASTEBIN.
> https://pastebin.com/wVSj1sF3 has a single piece of text : oh ee ess oh pee aitch ay gee you ess
>  Each one these sounds like a letter, which gives the answer **OESOPHAGUS**.

---

**Theory on Puzzle 2**
I haven't solved this one yet, but I do have a theory

> The title "Do not look behind you" seems to me to be hinting "Look in front of you", which leads me to the Keyboard I am currently typing on. For each row in the gird, highlighting the keys that is in that row reveals clumps of either 1 or 2 keys. My first idea is to go to Morse Code, since there's single keys and longer clumps together, but so far I haven't gotten any word out of it yet.

**Miscellanous note on the META**
Those Nonograms look SUPER non-unique, or at least very not logically solvable. But just to be sure, I ran them through [noq.solutions](https://www.noq.solutions/) to check, and while they are indeed very non-unique, I did find that

> the solutions it gave me has the shaded cells suspiciously clumped together, and the clumps look pretty similar in shape. 
> And now this is completely theory land, but some of the patterns I got reminds me or how some Conway's Game of Life patterns behave.

Again, that is completely my theory though. I contributed with two easy new solves, and now I will be going back and do the one you had solved myself for fun.

Comment: I think that the 4th nonogram has a unique solution and the third has only a handful of solutions.

Answer (score 6):

**Puzzle 2**

**Upd:** updated the answer as there was a mistake in the final step.

The answer is

> RASTERIZER

This is because

> the grid with letters can be uniquely split into given polyominoes such that the letters covered by each polyomino form the connected region on the keyboard.

The resulting figure is

> [image]

Now we note that

> each connected region on the keyboard is of shape O, C or L and "embraces" some letter. Those letters are E, I, Z, S, R, A, T, R, E, R (in the order in which the figures are given in the hint), and RASTERIZER is the only anagram.

The hint helped me in finding the solution:

> first, I noticed that the largest 8-cell region fits to the top and the letters are pretty close on the keyboard. Then the cross fitted nicely to the left-top with the same property.

> Next, I used some computer assistance to generate the assignment (in fact, it only generated admissible positions for all polyominoes).

> Finally, I realized that all connected regions on the keyboard are of the peculiar shape and looked at the surrounded characters. The colored square in the hint suggested that I'm on the right way.

Answer (score 3):

EDIT: Fixed the letters for grids 1 and 2 (I hadn't counted squares accurately)

**Puzzle 7**

Ever since I first saw this, I thought that the **-TION** was clueing subtraction, but I wasn't sure what to subtract it from.

As I played around with it some more, I came up with

> EQUATION

Removing the -TION and playing around with other words that contained the remaining letters, I came up with

> IN AD EQUA(-TION) SEE

or

> **INADEQUACY**

---

Adding this to the list of words, and assuming

> EFFERVESCE

for #5, then sorting alphabetically (A to Y), we end up with the grid

> ```
>  ANALYTICAL
>  DISSONANCE
>  EFFERVESCE
>  GREENBEANS
>  INADEQUACY
>  LYGOPHOBIA
>  NEEDLEFISH
>  OESOPHAGUS
>  RASTERIZER
>  SQUISHIEST
>  TIMOROUSLY
>  YELLOWTAIL
> ```

Plugging this into the nonograms solved by [Michael J](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/122160/4421), then anagramming the letters at the centre of each cross, I can get the words

> **CONGRATS** and **ACCOLADE**

from the 3rd and 4th grids respectively (assuming the ambiguous locations on the third grid are the upper right and lower left).

But the 1st and second grids don't seem to yield anything relevant.  I have

> **L(AS or NE)(OL or PD)UT**

for the first grid and

> **ASHRO** for the second.

This could be

> **HORAS** which is apparently a [Batak word to express gratefulness, happiness, and healthiness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horas), but that seems like a bit of a stretch.

I think I'm still missing something.

Note:

> Only the **R** from EFFERVESCE is used in my grid 3 & 4 solutions.  Perhaps that answer is wrong; since both grid 1 and grid 2 use letters from EFFERVESCE, that might be why I can't get a solution.
>  Using a different answer for EFFERVESCE could allow me to make **HALOS** for grid 2 and could also allow **PLAUDIT** or **CALLOUT** for grid 1, which all kind of fit the theme.

Comment: There is an error in Michael's top-right puzzle due to the ambiguity of the nonogram. The two floating crosshairs should focus on R3C6 and R6C8 instead, which gives you the letters to spell rot13(OENIB)!

Comment: Making sense of the ambiguities of the remaining top-left grid is harder. My hunch is that there is a missing 'I', which would make it possible to spell your 'P' suggestion in the plural.

Answer (score 2):

**Puzzle 7**

(Video Rebus)

The puzzle shows

> "(1+1=[picture of an eye])-TION" in a UTUUB window with a yellow progress bar.

The solution might be

> ADDITION.

Because

> The "1+1" clues the word ADD. The picture of an eye clues the letter "I". So ADD+I+TION = ADDITION. Furthermore, on UTUUB = YouTube, a yellow progress bar is that of an ADvertisement.

However this solution is likely wrong because

> all other solutions are 10-letter long (note: I just gathered others' solutions below.

> 1. LYGOPHOBIA

> 2.

> 3. ANALYTICAL

> 4. TIMOROUSLY

> 5.

> 6. SQUISHIEST

> 7. ADDITION???

> 8. DISSONANCE

> 9. YELLOWTAIL

> 10. OESOPHAGUS

> 11. GREENBEANS

> 12. NEEDLEFISH

> 13. (four words related to each other)

Comment: My thoughts are the "-TION" means subtract that suffix from the answer - EYE+EYE=<what can an eye do?> - Well, two eyes can perform "depth perception", so "AD-DEPTH-PERCEP", but that doesn't get me anywhere except "adept______"

Answer (score 1):

My thoughts on **puzzle 7**:

> As others already pointed out, the yellow bar indicates an ad = AD

> 1+1 = 2. Ideas I have for this are simplifying the word TWO to TU (as YouTube is simplified to UTUUB), or using other syllables connected to the number 2, e.g. DI or BI

> What can the eye do? See = C

> However, ADDICTION does not fit because it's only 9 letters.
>  Since the same image can be seen in the top right corner of the UTUUB screen, the solution could be ADDICTIONS, but that seems like a stretch

Another thought to question 7:

> It would be also rebus-style to view the -TION in the riddle not as a suffix, but as the call to remove TION from the word.
>  That however would require the bracketed equation to have 14 letters.

My thoughts on **puzzle 5**

> My guess to the two meanings is either a difference between British / American English, or between different languages.
>  I also thought of the word "EFFERVESCE" which fits sparkle and bubbly. However, I did not find a fitting language to fit brilliant into the picture.

Comment: This is actually promising. I considered changing the justification to ADD + IC, where "eye see" = IC, but then this doesn't take into account the yellow progress bar clue.

Answer (score 1):

OK, progress on subpuzzle 13.

> While solving the bottom-right puzzle, I found that the shaded sections are just a series of five-point stencils. Unfortunately, even just using stencils, the top-left puzzle and the bottom-left puzzle have non-unique solutions. I used MS Paint for my working and shaded in the solution in black and the empty squares in red, then left open the uncertain squares in white.  https://imgur.com/a/w3MEI9P

> Then, notice that each nonogram is 12 rows of 10. There are 12 puzzles, each giving a 10-letter word. I figure we're meant to plug each answer into each row and then the solution to each nonogram puts targets (the centre of the 5-point stencil) on each letter we're meant to use. Stiv noted also noted this and that we might need to arrange the 12 answers into alphabetical order before we're able to use the subpuzzle 13 solutions.

> If Suyluy is correct and subpuzzle 5's answer is EFFERVESCE, I suspect the answer to subpuzzle 7 has its 6th letter as T and that its 1st letter is either M or N so that the top-right nonogram spells out "ASTRO". This though then leaves the bottom-right nonogram seemingly spelling out DCGIEOAL. No idea.

Comment: Or is it 'DIAGONAL'?